# can i change the default encoding of my mysql server from latin-1 to utf-8?

Tags: mysql, encoding

can i change the default encoding of my mysql server on my computer from latin-1 to utf-8 ?

Comment: what kind of research have you done before posting here?

Answer (score 2):

sure you can. you can use your mysql gui software or run following queries:

```
// utf8 charset for multi-lingual support
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
mb_language("uni");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are working with PHP the answer from sarfraz is correct. You need to be aware of a number of other issues though such as changes to your actual code, header outputs, html charsets and many other things. A number of these things are discussed [here](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)